# How to correctly install PHPMailer + Messaging on Drupal 6

Tags: emails, notifications

I have a Drupal 6 site where I would like to use PHPMailer to send notifications about newly created nodes and such.
When I install PHPMailer 6.x-3.1, it needs Libraries and that phpmailer be placed under sites/libraries.
As I want different notifications for each content type, I installed 
Notifications 6.x-4.0-beta7 and Messaging 6.x-4.0-beta8.
What confuses me, is that I have two different places where PHPMailer can be configured, and they can have different settings: http://mysite.com/admin/messaging/settings/method/phpmailer and http://mysite.com/admin/settings/phpmailer.
Can anyone confirm my setup?

BTW: I had some trouble finding out that existing subscriptions had to be replaced with new (or edited in database) to move from notifications to notifications_content. Might be a help for others.

Answer (score 1):

I have chosen to not use the messaging_phpmailer module and only rely on the PHPMailer module. It works now, but notification/messaging is a mess on Drupal (at least with the beta-versions I'm running). Users email addresses are copied from table users to table notifications(.destination) and table messaging_destination(.address), and sometimes it is not. Maybe it happened during update, but I had to manually update the two via SQL updates, before notification works,. Until I did, the log was filling up with PHPMailer errors 'Invalid Address'.
What's worse, when a user changes his e-mail, the subscriptions copies are not updated, so notifications are still send to the first email address.
You have to tell your users to unsubscribe before changing email, and then subscribe again...

Kind regards
The Roadrunner